Manhwa mc where he is being targeted by someone who betrayed his family
So, the story begins when the MC practices swordsmanship with his father, which is later revealed to be not his real father but a knight who is the MC's real father.So, at that time when they were happy, someone attacked their adoptive father and it turned out to be a subordinate of their real father's traitor, he ran away and hid in a tree (Later in the story before the attack, a girl (like some childhood friend) will be introduced. I don't know her identity, but I think she's the granddaughter of the archmage) While they were hiding they were caught and their adopted brother or sister died protecting the mc where the girl pulled the mc's hand and when they were running they met They meet a mercenary who will be rewarded if they are taken to a wizard's tower and then paid (when they are paid, the girl is like hates the MC because the MC is the one who made MC family died). After that, the mercenary took care of the MC and after the time skip, the MC was taken care of in a guild created by the mercenary who saved him, where when the MC was given a sword, the sword always broke. He will meet an elf (I forgot whether the elf gender it's a girl or a boy because the design is a trap, even the guild leader (the mercenary who saved the mc) asked if it was a girl or a boy) At that time, the elf saw some kind of potential in the MC and he offered to give him a weapon that could withstand his power, but the guild leader said that all of the MC's swords had already been made by The best forger but the elf said that the forger he would recommend would make a legendary weapon so the quality would be guaranteed.
Oh yeah, I forgot to add that mc is prince of some kingdom.
This is the end of it, I remember the story but don't remember the title, so please help me. And sorry for my bad english, I use google translate.
